# How to save the state of a var using getX in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-mlkit, flutter-getx

Screenshot:
[Text Recognition Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmYgv.jpg)

The text detected from an image is saved in "var resultTxt", how can I save the state of all the lines detected by the ML model and use it on another page?

Text Recognition Code:

```
 doTextRecog() async {
    resultTxt = '';
    final FirebaseVisionImage visionImage =
        FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(_selectedFile);
    final VisionText visionText =
        await textRecognizer.processImage(visionImage);

    for (TextBlock block in visionText.blocks) {
      for (TextLine line in block.lines) {
        resultTxt += line.text + '\n';
      }
    }

    setState(() {
      resultTxt;
      print(resultTxt);
    });
    // textRecognizer.close();
  }
```

I'm already using the getX controller for my image path, but I'm not sure how to save a var with multiple lines of text and use it on another page.
Controller Code:

```
class PollImageController extends GetxController {
  RxString imageDisplay = ''.obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
  }

  void setImage(String image) {
    imageDisplay.value = image;
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also just handle all your Text Recognition functionality in a dedicated `GetxController` class.

Then you could call `doTextRecog()` and access the updated `RxString resultTxt` value from anywhere.

```
class TextRecognitionController extends GetxController {
  RxString resultTxt = ''.obs; 

  doTextRecog() async {
    final FirebaseVisionImage visionImage =
        FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(_selectedFile);
    final VisionText visionText =
        await textRecognizer.processImage(visionImage);

    for (TextBlock block in visionText.blocks) {
      for (TextLine line in block.lines) {
        resultTxt.value += line.text + '\n';
      }
    }
    
    print(resultTxt.value);
    // textRecognizer.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetxService` to share data in your app.

```dart
class SharedData extends GetxService {
  static SharedData get to => Get.find();
  final sharedText = ''.obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();
  }
}
```

```dart
 doTextRecog() async {
    resultTxt = '';
    final FirebaseVisionImage visionImage =
        FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(_selectedFile);
    final VisionText visionText =
        await textRecognizer.processImage(visionImage);

    for (TextBlock block in visionText.blocks) {
      for (TextLine line in block.lines) {
        resultTxt += line.text + '\n';
      }
    }

   // assign value
   SharedData.to.sharedText.value = resultTxt;
  }
```

Comment: How can I display the saved value on another page?

Comment: just  call this `SharedData.to.sharedText.value` in the other page.